# How to create quick controls like one in Android 4.04 browser

Tags: android

do you have any idea how to create the quick control that has been shown in the Android 4.0.4 default browser for a custom web view? That was very impressive, slide your thumb cross the edge of the screen and some menu items pop out at your finger tip. here is a sample link: http://www.droid-life.com/2012/02/07/tip-browser-quick-controls-expanded-in-android-4-0-4/

I've tried to implement that in a custom web view but failed

Comment: Well, the [Browser is open source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser), so you could start there.

Comment: Hi.I am looking for the same.Please provide me links or some snippet to achieve this if you have implemented it.Thanks.